error log shows nothing xampp php not displaying anything
XAMPP php is not working. I'm running Win10 and have the latest XAMPP version installed.
The XAMPP home page displays.
Clicking PHPInfo results in what is to be expected...a list of all the php info. v8.2.12
I have this directory tree for a project from a book:
C:\xampp\htdocs\book_apps\ch01_product_discount

The index.php page renders but it is supposed to calculate a % discount.
It displays "This page is not working" for the result page.
I'm using VS Code and live server to run the initial html file.
MySql is working fine.
The last lines in the log show:
[30-Jul-2024 14:19:23 America/Edmonton] Xdebug: [Step Debug] Time-out connecting to debugging client, waited: 200 ms. Tried: localhost:9003 (through xdebug.client_host/xdebug.client_port).

Ports are 80 and 443
I tried this code:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
$text = "Show me the errors!";
echo $text;
?>
</body>
</html>

and now it says this site can't be reached.

"127.0.0.1 refused to connect"

As many times as I try to run this, the error log never changes.
I just bought a book to start learning php and can't get a simple script to work.

rename file index.html to index.php

It's already got the .php extension

It's already got the .php extension...in the question you specifically said the file was called index.html. It needs to be called index.php before any PHP code can run inside it. If you've since changed your file name, please [edit] your question so that it's up to date.

I'm using VS Code and live server... VS Code's Live Server can't run PHP code. If you're using that then you aren't serving the page through Apache, which you will need to do in order to run any PHP scripts in a web page. Apache should be accessible through http://localhost, assuming it's started up (you can check this in the XAMPP control panel). Your PHP scripts will need to be within the Apache root directory in order to be served (once you're comfortable, you can look into how to serve pages from other folders on your disk, which might be more convenient in the long term)

ADyosn, First: question updated, apologies for the error. Second: Went through what you mentioned and diligently went through starting things step by step. It worked. Somehow I must have missed something in my prior attempts, however I'm sure I did things right the first time 'round. I have an issue with my system and spent 3 hrs with MS to fix it. They left things worse but maybe something else changed during there mess up. Or more probably, I just missed something previously. Anyways, thanks for your reply.
